# Sorting list but retaining the CSS markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Introduction

I currently have a list (with `ul` and `li`'s).

It's made sortable using jQuery:

```
$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
    update : function () {
    var items = $('#sortable1').sortable('serialize');
    alert(items);                       
    }
});
$( "#sortable1" ).disableSelection();
```

### The problem

This code moves the complete `li` item (including it's class - and thus it's markup).

### The question

Is there any way to match the target's destination class? I've setup a demo here: http://tinker.io/65292

So basically, when moving `item 1` one place down, `item 1` should become green and `item 2` should become `red`.

Additionally, when moving `item 1` two places down, `item 1` should be yellow, `item 2` should be red and finally `item 3` should be green.

This demo list only exists of four items, but realistically this could be any number.

### Demo code

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }

    .first { background-color: red; }
    .middle1 { background-color: green; }
    .middle2 { background-color: yellow; }
    .last { background-color: blue; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="first"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="middle1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="middle2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="last"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Link: http://tinker.io/65292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the css to target list elements based on index, and not class, and it will update automatically:

```
#sortable li:first-child { background-color: red; }
#sortable li:nth-child(2) { background-color: green; }
#sortable li:nth-child(3) { background-color: yellow; }
#sortable li:last-child { background-color: blue; }
```

[**TINKER**](http://tinker.io/65292/2)

Answer (score 3):

Use the nth-child css pseudo-class...

```
 #sortable li:nth-child(1) { background-color: red; }
#sortable li:nth-child(2) { background-color: green; }
#sortable li:nth-child(3) { background-color: yellow; }
#sortable li:nth-child(4)  { background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: Thanks, however I chose adeneo's answer due to the fact he points out the `first-child`, `last-child` plus he was slightly faster than you.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI's Sortable is based on the principle of moving entire DOM elements around.

As you correctly notice, the whole DOM object is moved including all its contents and all its attributes and, hence, its classes.

A couple of approaches occur to me:

1. change your CSS so that it doesn't require classes on the `<li>`s. It is possible to use pure CSS to make the first red, the second green, etc etc. You can use `nth-child` or `+` or `~` selectors in various ways. Then moving the `<li>`s around is fine and the appearance when they drop into place will be right.
2. Use javascript to remove and reapply the classes directly after each element move.